# how to read txt file into c++(dijkstra input)

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a text file with the following text inside:

```
----Text file----------------------
A B 4 C 2
B D 2 C 3 E 3
C B 1 D 4 E 5
D
E D 1
-----------------------------------
```

The meaning of this file is: distance from `A` to `B` is `4`, `A` to `C` is `2`, `B` to `D` is `2`, `B` to `C` is `3` ...etc

May I know how should I read this file into a c++ program variables?

I would like to make it into different set

```
(A,B,4)
(A,C,2)
(B,D,2)
...
...
(E,D,1)
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile("distance.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        istringstream ss(line);

        string name,name2;
        int var1, var2, var3;

        ss >> name >>name2>> var1 >> var2;
        //how do i scan the second alphabet in the same line?
    }
}
```

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "[c++] read file variable".  There are too many similar questions already.

Comment: What does "hot" mean in your title?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the whole line by whitespace, take the first element as your value and parse the rest in pairs. For each pair, add a new entry in your data structure.

Sample program doing all you asked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using std::ifstream;
using std::map;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::istringstream;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

typedef map< string, int > mapping;

map< string, mapping > data;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream inputFile("data.dat", ifstream::binary);
    string currentLine;
    while (getline(inputFile, currentLine))
    {
        if (currentLine.length() == 0)
            break;
        istringstream lineStream(currentLine);
        string node, destination;
        int length;
        lineStream >> node;
        while (lineStream >> destination)
        {
            length = 0;
            if (lineStream >> length)
            {
                if (data.find(node) == data.end())
                {
                    mapping newMapping;
                    data.insert(pair< string, mapping >(node, newMapping));
                }
                data[node].insert(pair< string, int >(destination, length));
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "dijkstra format error. exit." << endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    for (auto dataIt = data.begin(); dataIt != data.end(); ++dataIt)
    {
        mapping& currentMapping = dataIt->second;
        for (auto mappingIt = currentMapping.begin(); mappingIt != currentMapping.end(); ++mappingIt)
        {
            cout << dataIt->first << " <- (" << mappingIt->second << ") -> " << mappingIt->first << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output using your exact input file:

```
A <- (4) -> B
A <- (2) -> C
B <- (3) -> C
B <- (2) -> D
B <- (3) -> E
C <- (1) -> B
C <- (4) -> D
C <- (5) -> E
E <- (1) -> D
```

Comment: @andre's code illustrates your explanation very well. You should have a code sample also.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("distance.txt");
    string line;
    std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int> mapping;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> graph;

    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        istringstream ss(line);
        string name;
        ss >> name;
        while(ss >> line) {
             int value = 0;
             if(!(ss >> value)) //error
             graph[name] = line;
             mapping[std::make_pair(name, line)] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change the file design i think it will easy to read you can break the line on white spaces or you can use comma to separate the values here design mean...

A B C 
A  0 3 6 
B  1 0 1 
C  0 0 7

**first Row**
it show all outgoing edges of A.
cost 0 show that their is no edge between the nodes
form A to A cost is 0
form A to B cost is 3
form A to c cost is 6
and similarly other rows....